# how to cut tag in string with PHP

Tags: php, html

I Have a problem with this output receive value.

```
  $simple="<TRAN_ID>17564_36428.1354_4159</TRAN_ID>
           <TRAN_DATE>20160201</TRAN_DATE>
           <TRAN_TIME>10:07:08</TRAN_TIME>
           <ERROR_CODE>1</ERROR_CODE>
           <ERROR_DESC>Not Input Policy</ERROR_DESC>
           <POLICY_NBR></POLICY_NBR>";
```

I want to cut the code  with PHP.

```
    TRAN_ID = ?
    TRAND_DATE = ?
    ERROR_CODE = ?
    ERROR_DESC = ?
```

How can i do it. sorry my english is bad. 
Thanks.

Comment: also, I believe you are either looking for substr or preg_replace

Comment: It is the value received from the customer side .. advice or example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PHP's SimpleXML library, like so:

```
<?php
    $str ="<TRANS><TRAN_ID>17564_36428.1354_4159</TRAN_ID><TRAN_DATE>20160201</TRAN_DATE><TRAN_TIME>10:07:08</TRAN_TIME><ERROR_CODE>1</ERROR_CODE><ERROR_DESC>Not Input Policy</ERROR_DESC><POLICY_NBR></POLICY_NBR></TRANS>";

    $transaction = simplexml_load_string($str);

    echo $transaction->TRAN_ID.PHP_EOL;
    echo $transaction->TRAN_DATE.PHP_EOL;
    echo $transaction->TRAN_TIME.PHP_EOL;
    echo $transaction->ERROR_CODE.PHP_EOL;
    echo $transaction->ERROR_DESC.PHP_EOL;
    echo $transaction->POLICY_NBR.PHP_EOL;
```

Note that I added **<TRANS>** start and end tags to your string.

If the data always looks like the sample, this should work okay.

Comment: I should have thought of this. I can't believe I didn't.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
function getTextBetweenTags($string, $tagname) {
    $pattern = "/<$tagname ?.*>(.*)<\/$tagname>/";
    preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
}

$str = '<textformat leading="2"><p align="left"><font size="10">get me</font></p></textformat>';
$txt = getTextBetweenTags($str, "font");
echo $txt;
?>
```